# How do I convert (daily) date to month date?

Tags: stata

In Stata, how do I convert date in the form of:

```
09mar2005 00:00:00
```

to a month-year variable?

If it matters, the date format is `%tc`.

What I have in mind is to plot monthly averages (instead of the daily average I have) of variables across time.

Comment: It is really important to know that your date-time variable is numeric!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get where you are now, you or somebody else may have done something like this:

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen earlier = "09mar2005 00:00:00"
gen double nowhave = clock(earlier, "DMY hms") 
format nowhave %tc 
list 

     +-----------------------------------------+
     |            earlier              nowhave |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. | 09mar2005 00:00:00   09mar2005 00:00:00 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

Note that a string date and a numeric date-time variable with appropriate date-time format `%tc` just look the same when you `list` them, but they are quite different beasts.

To get where you want to be -- with a monthly date -- you convert from clock (date-time) to daily to monthly:

```
gen mdate = mofd(dofc(nowhave)) 

format mdate %tm 

list 

     +--------------------------------------------------+
     |            earlier              nowhave    mdate |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 09mar2005 00:00:00   09mar2005 00:00:00   2005m3 |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

All is documented at `help datetime`. The function names stand for `m`onth `of d`aily date and `d`aily date `of c`lock.