# Convert strings to HRF monthly dates

Tags: stata

I imported from Excel as variable names, and `reshape`d into "observations", a series of strings (`5s`) that represent dates.

These dates (stored in the variable `daate`) have the form `ddnn20Y`: `1108`, which means 1 Jan 2008; `1912`, which means 1 Sep 2012; or `11210`, which means 1 Dec 2010. That is they are ***not*** Stata internal form (SIF) dates held as strings!

I have tried more things than I can remember (i.e.: formatting directly with `format daate %tdddnn20YY` or `gen date = date(daate, "DM20Y")`).

I have read the `help datetime` and tried to implement the `HRF-to-SIF Functions` (which in my case I think should be the first step) unsuccessfully.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828333/how-do-i-convert-daily-date-to-month-date) almost gets me to the solution: first by `destring`ing `daate` to `int`, and then by `gen date = mofd(daate); format date %tm`; but it was yet another unsuccessful approach.

Example data:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str12 isin str5 daate double price
"AEA000201011" "11008" 3.53
"AEA000201011" "11009" 2.44
"AEA000201011" "11010" 2.32
"AEA000201011" "11011" 2.86
"AEA000201011" "11012" 3.28
"AEA000201011" "11013" 4.93
"AEA000201011" "11014"  8.6
"AEA000201011" "11015" 7.75
"AEA000201011" "1108"  5.34
"AEA000201011" "1109"  1.78
"AEA000201011" "1110"  1.61
"AEA000201011" "11108" 2.63
"AEA000201011" "11109"    2
"AEA000201011" "1111"  2.14
"AEA000201011" "11110" 2.43
"AEA000201011" "11111" 2.94
"AEA000201011" "11112" 3.29
"AEA000201011" "11113"    5
"AEA000201011" "11114" 7.97
"AEA000201011" "11115" 7.09
"AEA000201011" "1112"  2.77
"AEA000201011" "1113"  3.01
"AEA000201011" "1114"   6.5
"AEA000201011" "1115"  7.03
"AEA000201011" "11208" 2.55
"AEA000201011" "11209" 1.82
"AEA000201011" "11210"  2.3
"AEA000201011" "11211" 2.85
"AEA000201011" "11212" 2.98
"AEA000201011" "11213"  5.4
"AEA000201011" "11214" 6.66
"AEA000201011" "11215" 6.25
"AEA000201011" "1208"  5.58
"AEA000201011" "1209"  1.48
"AEA000201011" "1210"  1.59
"AEA000201011" "1211"  2.15
"AEA000201011" "1212"  2.91
"AEA000201011" "1213"   3.6
"AEA000201011" "1214"  6.79
"AEA000201011" "1215"  7.18
"AEA000201011" "1308"  5.37
"AEA000201011" "1309"  1.74
"AEA000201011" "1310"  1.66
"AEA000201011" "1311"  2.21
"AEA000201011" "1312"  3.23
"AEA000201011" "1313"  4.01
"AEA000201011" "1314"  7.15
"AEA000201011" "1315"   7.6
"AEA000201011" "1408"  5.41
"AEA000201011" "1409"  1.64
"AEA000201011" "1410"  2.09
"AEA000201011" "1411"  2.52
"AEA000201011" "1412"  3.23
"AEA000201011" "1413"  4.13
"AEA000201011" "1414"  7.36
"AEA000201011" "1415"  6.66
"AEA000201011" "1508"  5.82
"AEA000201011" "1509"  1.56
"AEA000201011" "1510"  1.89
"AEA000201011" "1511"  2.87
"AEA000201011" "1512"  3.31
"AEA000201011" "1513"  4.66
"AEA000201011" "1514"   7.8
"AEA000201011" "1515"  7.36
"AEA000201011" "1608"  5.25
"AEA000201011" "1609"  1.78
"AEA000201011" "1610"  1.63
"AEA000201011" "1611"  2.92
"AEA000201011" "1612"  2.91
"AEA000201011" "1613"  4.95
"AEA000201011" "1614"  8.65
"AEA000201011" "1615"  7.57
"AEA000201011" "1708"   5.2
"AEA000201011" "1709"  1.59
"AEA000201011" "1710"  1.57
"AEA000201011" "1711"  3.13
"AEA000201011" "1712"  3.36
"AEA000201011" "1713"     5
"AEA000201011" "1714"   7.6
"AEA000201011" "1715"  7.55
"AEA000201011" "1808"  5.04
"AEA000201011" "1809"  1.99
"AEA000201011" "1810"  1.65
"AEA000201011" "1811"  3.11
"AEA000201011" "1812"  3.37
"AEA000201011" "1813"  5.33
"AEA000201011" "1814"   8.7
"AEA000201011" "1815"  8.12
"AEA000201011" "1908"   4.1
"AEA000201011" "1909"  1.98
"AEA000201011" "1910"  1.68
"AEA000201011" "1911"  2.98
"AEA000201011" "1912"   3.3
"AEA000201011" "1913"  5.01
"AEA000201011" "1914"  8.11
"AEA000201011" "1915"  7.76
"AEA000701010" "11008" 2.14
"AEA000701010" "11009"  .78
"AEA000701010" "11010"  .67
"AEA000701010" "11011"  .58
end
```

Comment: `destring` followed by taking the result literally can't work as then October, November and December dates are roughly 10000 more than dates in other months. The input has to be parsed properly.

Comment: The data example is hard work because the dates are not in date order.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Thank you very much for your answer; it makes everything regarding dates really clear now! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution relies on tidying up the original first to get closer to what Stata prefers, so allowing careful checks. We don't need all your data example (but thanks). As @Pearly Spencer points out, these are really monthly dates presented as daily dates.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str5 daate
"11008"
"11009"
"11010"
"11011"
"11012"
"11013"
"11014"
"11015"
"1108" 
"1109" 
"1110" 
"11108"
"11109"
"1111" 
"11110"
"11111"
"11112"
"11113"
"11114"
"11115"
"1112" 
"1113" 
"1114" 
"1115" 
"11208"
"11209"
"11210"
"11211"
"11212"
"11213"
"11214"
"11215"
"1208" 
"1209" 
"1210" 
"1211" 
"1212" 
"1213" 
"1214" 
"1215" 
"1308" 
"1309" 
"1310" 
"1311" 
"1312" 
"1313" 
"1314" 
"1315" 
"1408" 
"1409" 
"1410" 
"1411" 
"1412" 
"1413" 
"1414" 
"1415" 
"1508" 
"1509" 
"1510" 
"1511" 
"1512" 
"1513" 
"1514" 
"1515" 
"1608" 
"1609" 
"1610" 
"1611" 
"1612" 
"1613" 
"1614" 
"1615" 
"1708" 
"1709" 
"1710" 
"1711" 
"1712" 
"1713" 
"1714" 
"1715" 
"1808" 
"1809" 
"1810" 
"1811" 
"1812" 
"1813" 
"1814" 
"1815" 
"1908" 
"1909" 
"1910" 
"1911" 
"1912" 
"1913" 
"1914" 
"1915" 
end

gen better = substr(daate, 1, 1) + ///
" " + substr(daate, 2, length(daate) - 3) + ///
" 20" + substr(daate, -2, 2) 

gen mdate = mofd(daily(better, "DMY")) 

sort mdate 

format mdate %tm 

gen year = year(daily(better, "DMY")) 

list if year <= 2009 , sepby(year) 

     +------------------------------------+
     | daate      better     mdate   year |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. |  1108    1 1 2008    2008m1   2008 |
  2. |  1208    1 2 2008    2008m2   2008 |
  3. |  1308    1 3 2008    2008m3   2008 |
  4. |  1408    1 4 2008    2008m4   2008 |
  5. |  1508    1 5 2008    2008m5   2008 |
  6. |  1608    1 6 2008    2008m6   2008 |
  7. |  1708    1 7 2008    2008m7   2008 |
  8. |  1808    1 8 2008    2008m8   2008 |
  9. |  1908    1 9 2008    2008m9   2008 |
 10. | 11008   1 10 2008   2008m10   2008 |
 11. | 11108   1 11 2008   2008m11   2008 |
 12. | 11208   1 12 2008   2008m12   2008 |
     |------------------------------------|
 13. |  1109    1 1 2009    2009m1   2009 |
 14. |  1209    1 2 2009    2009m2   2009 |
 15. |  1309    1 3 2009    2009m3   2009 |
 16. |  1409    1 4 2009    2009m4   2009 |
 17. |  1509    1 5 2009    2009m5   2009 |
 18. |  1609    1 6 2009    2009m6   2009 |
 19. |  1709    1 7 2009    2009m7   2009 |
 20. |  1809    1 8 2009    2009m8   2009 |
 21. |  1909    1 9 2009    2009m9   2009 |
 22. | 11009   1 10 2009   2009m10   2009 |
 23. | 11109   1 11 2009   2009m11   2009 |
 24. | 11209   1 12 2009   2009m12   2009 |
     +------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

String to numeric date translation *functions* (`help datetime_translation`) 
should not be confused with display *formats* for dates and times 
(`help datetime_display_formats`).

The former have dedicated codes for *masks* and do **not** accept the *details* codes of the latter. In your example, `ddnn20Y` is a display format detail code and thus not a valid mask for the `date()` function.

Masks for datetime translation require combinations of `D`, `M`, `Y` and `h`,
`m`, `s` codes. However, implementation is dependent on the human-readable-form date string to be translated.

For example, the following is valid:

```
. display date("011008", "DM20Y")
17806
```

In contrast, the one below is not:

```
. display date("11008", "DM20Y")
.
```

Any string that deviates from Stata's specifications for datetime translation
should be first manupulated using the built-in string functions as in @NickCox's
answer.